# What is the source of the additions before תתקבל צלותהון, יהא שלמא, עושה שלום in Kaddish Tiskabel?

Tags: minhag, tefilla, kaddish, nuschaot

In Kaddish Tiskabel, there are [parts to be said](http://opensiddur.org/wp-content/uploads/2010/10/Siddur-Bnei-Ashkenaz-v.1.12.1.pdf) (see page 131) by the congregation just before the three phrases that begin: תתקבל  צלותהון, יהא שלמא, עושה שלום.

These do not appear in all siddurim and I have not observed many who say them.

What is their source?

Which traditions say them? (The link above is to a German Rite Siddur.)

Comment: they appear in my סדור תפלה השלם but I don't know if that represents any particular tradition.

Comment: Can you try to find a link that goes straight to the correct page or maybe insert a page number to the question?

Comment: @DoubleAA Thank you. Page number inserted in question.

Answer (score 1):

I have seen it in the siddur Avodat Yisrael. I also think that the piskei tshuvos siman 56 talks about this.

Answer (score 1):

The פסוקים in the middle of קדיש‎ (קבל ברחמים, יהי שם ד׳, עזרי מעם ד׳) are not mentioned by the ראשונים, but were added in the first printed סידורים. The source for their recital is unclear, therefore, some are accustomed to say them while others are not.

Comment: I notice in the above linked siddur, you offer grammatically correct alternatives for women to use for certain of the Birkot HaShachar. Perhaps you would know some information about this custom to add to this question http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/13653/759