# Why extra phrases in the full kaddish in the Artscroll siddur?

Tags: kaddish

The Artscroll siddur has 3 one line congregational responses after parts of the tiskabel kaddish (e.g., kabayl brachamim uv'ratzon es tefilasanu).  The siddur says these lines are said by the congregation.  There is no indication that the responses are optional or said by some.  I have never heard them said and they do not appear in other major siddurim (Birnbaum, Sacks, Metzuda).  What is the source of these responses and why does Artscroll give such strong direction that they be said?

Comment: These appear in many siddurim

Comment: @DoubleAA But the responses do _not_ appear in some widely used siddurim. So why does Artscroll state simply "Cong" indicating that it is always said?  In other places, Artscroll says, in effect, some do and some don't.

Comment: There are lots of differences between siddurim. They don't warn you about every difference. You are way overstating this.

Comment: I have heard Yekkes in Munk's shul in London who say this

Comment: possible duplicate https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/15806/759

Comment: In the Etz Chaim (Yekkish) shul in Strasbourg they also said these aloud. Mostly the Yekkes say them in an undertone. IIRC the Vilna Gaon was against saying them and thus they were dropped by many eventually.

Answer (score 1):

They appear in Wolf Heidenheim's siddur (e.g [p100 here](http://opensiddur.org/wp-content/uploads/2010/11/Tefiloh-Sefas-Yisroel-1-Shacharit.pdf)). Artscroll's siddur claims that his this is one of their sources.

Comment: Where does the Artscroll siddur say this, pls.

Comment: @YehudaW I don't have one a hand, but IIRC, the preface states so.

Comment: Why does Artscroll give such strong direction that the responses be said, if they are so widely not said? (Elsewhere, Artscroll says, in effect, some do and some don't.)

Comment: @YehudaW Is the directive really that strong? I think they tend on the side of inclusion, to maximize the number of customs for which the siddur is usable.

Comment: @YehudaW I personally find it distracting that a siddur gives me "choices", usually in he form of parallel texts or parenthesised words/phrases. Few modern siddurim take a stance. Muncatch's siddurim (what I use) are an exception, as the Muncatcher Rov put great emphasis on determining a proper nusach.

Comment: Art Scroll was created to cater to a growing primarily "Hebrew ignorant" crowd. That's not meant to be insulting - it's just describing the facts. Within that crowd, there were, and still are, multiple nuscha'ot, minhagim, interpretations, etc. that they cater to, hence the choices. If you think about it, their strategy is not much difference than the Ezrat Torah Luach that many Orthodox shuls use, that also give you some "choices". Nothing wrong with that. Of course, one choice is not to use Art Scroll at all, if that's your desire :-)