# Historic, variant wording for birkat hamazon for women?

Tags: history, women, nuschaot, bentching

The Mishna Berura ([halachot birchat hamazon, siman 187](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14164&st=&pgnum=167)) mentions a variant wording of the birkat hamazon that is said by women.  Precisely what is this wording and when was it used and when was it abandoned?

Comment: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/13378/759

Comment: If you are talking about the practice mentioned in the Rama (187:3), it just seems like the women would omit the phrases in question (perhaps including *v'al chukecha*...?).

Comment: @fred  Your surmise is reasonable.  I am looking for more specifics.

Comment: @YehudaW It's more than reasonable that the different "variant" merely involves skipping the phrases in question - it is clear that that's what it means because that's what the Rama says. The only real question is whether "תורה" is limited to "ועל תורתך שלמדתנו" or whether it also includes "ועל חקיך שהודעתנו" (as perhaps the latter phrase is primarily intended to refer to the obligation to perform the commandments rather than the obligation to study Torah).

Comment: @fred OK. More than reasonable.  But is there a specific source with the specific wording? The question also asks, when was it used and when was it abandoned?

Comment: Technically, it's not the Mishna Berura who's mentioning the variant reading; it's the Rama in the name of the Kol Bo. (The MB justifies the unabridged, contemporary version which women were already using in his day.)

Comment: Check out the hakdama of the Magen Abraham to siman קצב.
Also Kaf HaChaim קפז incise 4 . Right there at the end of the hakdama to that siman
is
the wording of the short version by r' naftali;
the MA cites it from the Bach and says this is the most accepted version. So its very old and very accepted so i thought it may be interesting

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is pretty common in old* Siddurim. You can see omitting just ועל בריתך שחתמת בבשרינו on Hebrewbooks [here](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=44668&st=&pgnum=3) [here](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=10548&st=&pgnum=3) [here](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=42111&st=&pgnum=3) [here](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=44295&st=&pgnum=3) and [here](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=10547&st=&pgnum=2) and on Hebrewmanuscripts.org manuscript #747. You can see omitting that phrase plus ועל תורתך שלימדתנו on Hebrewbooks [here](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=45010&st=&pgnum=10) and on Hebrewmanuscripts.org manuscript #1762. [This siddur](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=20154&st=&pgnum=7) is not clear how much exactly to omit.

*<sub>Those presented here were published between 1579 and 1815</sub>

Comment: +1 Good stuff, but I would really like to know when women stopped being makpid to leave out the words that make no sense. Theoretically, at the times of the Ramma they still understood Lashon HaKodesh, and later when they didn't, they didn't realize they shouldn't be saying it, but that's just a theory.

Comment: @user6591 It's not like one day they decided to stop. Change happens slowly over 500 years.

Comment: 100% but at some point even the printers didn't care. There were many eastern European ladies who didn't bentch for themselves but were yotze with their fathers/husbands. Could be that helped the mistake come about. Funny thing is many of those ladies had the minhag to say kidush and and hamotzi along with or after their man.

Comment: @user6591 Is it so clearly a mistake? The words are plural not singular and they are part of the people that has this commandment (as noted by the Mishna Berurah).

Comment: @loewian The words don't say ועל מצוות מילה שציותנו. Then your argument might hold.

Comment: @DoubleAA If "ציותנו" can refer to the nation as a whole, why can't "בשרינו" ("Our flesh" i.e. the flesh of our fathers, husbands, brother, and [especially] sons.)

Comment: @user6591 I'd also add that if the gender-based shinuy matbe'ah is only mentioned in the Kol Bo, the burden of proof is on the one claiming the silent majority of Rishonim were also on board.

Comment: @loewian ummm... that's not a remotely normal use of "our"? Re your second comment: it's Kol Bo in the name of the Raavad, and it's mentioned in Rashi and Tosfot (Arachin 3a), which is nothing to sneeze at. Plus most women back then weren't bentching at all (due to illiteracy), just listening to their husbands when they would bentch aloud.

Comment: @DoubleAA and I suppose Tosfos in Brachos might be readable that way too...

Comment: @Ioewian seffer hachinuch #606 mitzvas kria al haBikurim, "and from this (people who don't bring because they can't say from the land which you gave us) we should learn concerning our prayers and beseeching before Hashem to be very scrupulous and careful with our words not to say something to Hashem unless it is correctly worded, remember this my son and Girard it".

Comment: @DoubleAA  At least one of these seems to be in Yiddish (hebrewbooks_org_44668_3.pdf).  What does it say?  (I do not read Yiddish and do not know anyone who does.)

Comment: @YehudaW I don't read Yiddish either. I just looked at the Hebrew parts.

Comment: https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:The_National_Library_of_Israel_-_The_Daily_Prayers_translated_from_Hebrew_to_Marathi_1388864_2340601-10-0376_WEB.jpg

Answer (score 6):

The Italian *nusach* Bnei Roma omits ועל בריתך שחסמת בבשרנו for women.

Comment: MB is ashkenaz, so there must be more to it than that.  In any case, is there a Bnei Roma siddur on line?